# ActionBarSherlock ViewPager Swipe tab order in RTL languages?

Tags: android, tabs, actionbarsherlock

I created a swipe tab using ActionBarSherlock ViewPager according to the 
[Tutorial](http://www.androidbegin.com/tutorial/android-actionbarsherlock-viewpager-tabs-tutorial)

When I change the language of phone to a RTL language (like Persian or Arabic) the swipe tab order is changing (the first tab goes to end and last tab goes to the front).

How can I prevent this reordering?